# AWS RDS Automated Backup and Snapshots - how to make both?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot, database-backups, amazon-aurora

I'm familiar with the differences between "Automated Backups" and Snapshots. I'm trying to backup using both of them, but from the Modify-section of DB I find only Backup and Backtrack, and to my understanding, the backups from the Backup-section ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu4mi.png ) should be going under "Automated Backups", right? But they're going under Automated Snapshots.

How do I create Automated Backup instead of snapshot?

E. I'm Using Amazon Aurora, I suppose that makes it a little different than other RDS!

Answer (score 0):

Automated backups are always enabled on Amazon Aurora DB Instances.

Comment: Yes, but they are under snapshots, not under "Automated backups". Is this some kind of "Aurora only" thing, I've understood that Aurora is a little special with backups?
https://i.imgur.com/viYB0Jd.png
https://i.imgur.com/QPN1lwm.png

Comment: Yes, you cannot disable automated backups on Aurora. It is by design. You can only  create snapshots, or not create.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to understand the difference between a snapshot & an automated backup:

> Amazon RDS creates and saves automated backups of your DB instance. Amazon RDS creates a storage volume snapshot of your DB instance, backing up the entire DB instance and not just individual databases.

Both of which are automatically active when you create an RDS unless you specify otherwise while creating the RDS instance:

[image]

Secondly regarding your amazon aurora question, it does the same thing as a normal RDS creating automated backups & snapshots:

> Automated backups are always enabled on Amazon Aurora DB Instances. Backups do not impact database performance.

References: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html
https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/#Backup_and_Restore